# Git for Windows: can't run any commands after command git config --list

Tags: git, github, command-line, git-bash, github-for-windows

I using git bash in windows 7 environments. I start git bash and type `git config --list` but after that I can't run any commands and git bash only show `(end)` in screen. I don't know what happen and that's command is worked properly before.
Screenshots:

[image: First-Error]

[image: Second-Error]

Comment: Please don't link to the images containing errors. Add them directly to your post.

Comment: Thanks for your advices

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like `git config --list` has opened `less` for showing the config list. You can enter `:q` to exit `less`.

Comment: … and hit `Enter` after writing `:q`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Simply Press <kbd>:</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to exit the Output.